# Android EditText и Rx

Tags: android, kotlin, rxandroid

Помогите пожалуйста, есть несколько EditText. Отслеживаются изменения в них. И в зависимости какие данные введены изменяются другие EditText. Как можно блокировать наблюдения за определенными EditText, т.к. их изменения влекут изменения в других и так до бесконечности.

```
class RxEditText {

companion object {
    fun getTextWatcherObservable(editText: EditText): Observable<String> {
        var subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                if(!s.isNullOrEmpty())
                    subject.onNext(s.toString())
            }

        })
        return subject
    }
}}
```

Класс SearchByCk24Fragment

```
class SearchByCk24Fragment: Fragment() {

    ck42xObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_x.editText!!)
    ck42yObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_y.editText!!)

    ck42latitudeDegObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_latitude_deg.editText!!)
    ck42latitudeMinObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_latitude_min.editText!!)
    ck42latitudeSecObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_latitude_sec.editText!!)

    ck42longitudeDegObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_longitude_deg.editText!!)
    ck42longitudeMinObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_longitude_min.editText!!)
    ck42longitudeSecObservable = RxEditText.getTextWatcherObservable(ck_42_longitude_sec.editText!!)




    Observable.combineLatest(ck42latitudeDegObservable, ck42latitudeMinObservable, ck42latitudeSecObservable,
            ck42longitudeDegObservable, ck42longitudeMinObservable, ck42longitudeSecObservable,
            Function6<String, String, String, String, String, String, Coordinates> { lat_deg, lat_min, lat_sec, lon_deg, lon_min, lon_sec ->
                Coordinates(lat_deg.toInt(), lat_min.toInt(), lat_sec.toDouble(),
                        lon_deg.toInt(), lon_min.toInt(), lon_sec.toDouble())
            })
            .subscribe (
                    { updateUi(it) }, // onNext
                    { Toast.makeText(context, it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }, // onError
                    {

                    }, // onComplete
                    {

                    } // onSubscribe
            )

    Observable.combineLatest(ck42xObservable, ck42yObservable,
            BiFunction<String, String, Coordinates> { ck42x, ck42y -> Coordinates(ck42x.toInt(), ck42y.toInt()) })
            .subscribe(
                    { updateUi(it) }, // onNext
                    { Toast.makeText(context, it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }, // OnError
                    {

                    }, // OnComplete
                    {

                    } // OnSubscribe
            )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отписываться от прослушки таким способом:

```
editText.removeTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcher);
```